# <a href="#divtagid"> is not able to open the div tag when used from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display the content of div with id "hello" in maindiv when clicked on href "Click Here": but that's not working.

Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newhtml = '<a href="#hello"> Click Here</a>';
  $('maindiv').append('newhtml');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">//empty</div>
<div id="hello">
  <h1> Hello World </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not how this works. `#hello` is used for anchors. Start reading html and jQuery manuals to do this. You need to add an onclick handler to the a element.

Comment: @Mouser - No, having an anchor reference another element on the same page by its id *is* a valid and common technique. (Back in the old days the other element had to be an anchor too, and it was referenced by name, but any element by id is now standard.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I know, but I think that isn't what the OP is asking us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question correctly; you want to load the document. Populate `#maindiv` with a link. When a user clicks on the link it should move the content of `#hello` to the `maindiv`.

To get you started:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newhtml='<a href="#hello"> Click Here</a>';
    $('#maindiv').append(newhtml);
}
```

The code above will add the html to the `maindiv` correctly. It corrects your coding. But I think that isn't what you were looking for. You want the newly inserted link to also put the content of `hello` into the main div. The code below should do that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newhtml='<a href="javascript: void(0)"> Click Here</a>';
    $('#maindiv').append(newhtml);
    $('#maindiv a').click(function(){
        $('#maindiv').append($("#hello h1"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8z3dz109/1/

Comment: Thanks for helping dude! You have used $('#maindiv').append($("#hello h1")); h1 explicitly , what if there are multiple tags? h1 h2 h3 p and so on

Comment: @user1079341 just insert more selectors like this: `append($("#hello h1"), $("#hello h2"))`

Comment: ok is there any other way? because i have around 200 tags to be inserted under maindiv :(

Comment: Yes, there is. Do the tags have something in common? Like a classname or tagname?. BTW this answer solved your problem posted.

Comment: @user1079341 use `append($("#hello").contents())`. Will do the trick. Selects all content from `hello` and adds it to `maindiv`. Start reading this: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

change `$('maindiv').append('newhtml');` to  `$('#maindiv').append(newhtml);`

```
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="hello">
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

```
$(function(){
    var newhtml='<a href="#hello"> Click Here</a>';
    $('#maindiv').append(newhtml);
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5vwnL1xk/2/)

Comment: made the above changes but still its not working. Even its not working on ur fiddle link. Hello world should be printed on clicking the link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that you have quotes around *newhtml*. Variables do not need to have quotes around them.

```
$('#maindiv').append(newhtml);
```

Also, changed the *'maindiv'* to have a **#** in front because you must do that when referring to HTML id's in JQuery. And yeah... This is JQuery.

Comment: Do you mean "quotes"? The parentheses are required in order to call `append`.